# What is not an instanceof Class in java?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to get a conditional to evaluate to false.  I have a Field which is a Map that I've gotten from looking at `declaredFields`.  What can the Map parameterized type `type` be that will cause the conditional to be false?

```
// field is a Map from a class using reflection (declaredFields)
Type type = ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[i]
if (type instanceof Class) {
    everthingsAClass()
} else {
    whatIsntAClass()
}
```

Comment: `null` will always return `false` in an `instanceof` check, but you can't use it as a type argument anyway. Not sure what a raw type would return, but probably `Object`.

Comment: Array types and primitives, perhaps?

Comment: More parameterized types.

Answer (score 2):

There are various non-public classes other than `Class` that indirectly implement `Type`.

For example  `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl` implements `TypeVariable` which is an interface that extends `Type`.

Other examples include `GenericArrayTypeImpl`, `ParameterizedTypeImpl` and `WildcardTypeImpl`.

Instances of these classes *may be* returned by various reflection API methods such as the `getGenericInterfaces` and `getGenericSuperclass` methods of `Class`.